# How to print a string initially, then set a bit that is checked so will not print again in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like in the old game zork, You see a description of the room when you first enter it. Then when you come back to the room, it no longer shows the description unless you specifically call it. I am trying to determine what is the best method to accomplish it without being given the whole solution

I have tried setting a variable then using if statements that checks the variable, have tried a list where a the 0 index is checked for either a 0(zero) or 1 is in the 0 index. I have not tried a while loop as it seems incorrect.

```
def westOfHouse():
    os.system('cls')
    print "WEST OF HOUSE"

    descript = "You are on the west side of a house. There is a mailbox here."
    action = str(raw_input(">> "))

    if action.lower() == str("w" or "west"):
        forest()
    elif action.lower() == str("n" or "north" or "nw" or "northwest"):
        northOfHouse()
    elif action.lower() == str("s" or "south" or "se" or "southeast"):
        southOfHouse()
    elif action.lower() == str("sw" or "southwest"):
        stoneBarrow()
    else:
        print "You cannot go in that direction"
        westOfHouse()
```

I want to be able to go to another room and come back and not be shown the description again unless specifically called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a database, and store each room in that database. Example of
a corresponding `Room` class in pseudocode:

```
class Room:
    id          = String()        
    name        = String()
    description = String()
    visited     = Boolean()
    travel      = Dict()     # {"n": 2, "nw": 2, "s": 3, ...}
    actions     = Dict()     # {"pick": some_code_block_or_method, ...}
    ...
```

and then write your central logic to withdraw each room from a database and act on it. For example:

```
def substitute(action):
    # helper method to condense synonyms
    if action in ["n", "north"]:
        return "north"
    elif action in ["nw", "northwest"]:
        return "northwest"
    ...
    else:
        return action

room_id = 1  # room WEST OF HOUSE
while True:
    current_room = Room.get(id=room_id)  # get the instance for the room we're in
    os.system('cls')
    print(current_room.name)

    if not current_room.visited:
        print(current_room.description)
        current_room.visited = True
        current_room.save()
    action = str(raw_input(">> "))
    action = substitute(action.lower())

    if action in current_room.travel:
        room_id = current_room.travel[action]
    elif action in current_room.actions:
        current_room.actions[action]()
    else:
        print("Command not understood")
```

Note that none of this code is meant to actually work and you'd have to think through your design a bit more before actually building something like this. - but this is the approach I would take.

Comment: Apologies in advance if my questions seem naive as I have only been practicing Python for a few days and a lot of this is over my head at the moment. 1)When you say make a database, that is the class object you are referring to? 2) Is the "current_room.save()" storing the "True" into the class object?

Comment: (1) It would be an external database (e.g. MySQL) to which you connect using a python library such as `sqlalchemy`. I forget the syntax for sqlalchemy in particular, but you can read the docs for it. (2) Yes - we load the object, change it, and then save its current state. (3) If you don't want to get into full-on databases, you could also rig up a text-based file (`csv` is a good format and python has a standard library for it) and write some methods in a custom `Room` class to load or save to or from that file. Lots of possible solutions - experiment, and see what works for you!